# Jelastic giving 502 Application down frequently

Tags: glassfish, jelastic

I recently tried using Jelastic trial version.I created 3 or 4 accounts on it.On each of the environment that i created i used Glassfish server and MongoDB database.All those environments crashed within a day and i get 502 Application Down Error.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

As a potential cause it could be a lack of resources (cloudlets). GlassFish is a heavy application server, in Jelastic it requires 6 cloudlets at least.
You need to check your application server's logs to get the cause of failure in details.1
If it does not help, contact your support by clicking Help | Contact Support.